# Package Clojure and Java(springboot) source codes into a JAR file with leiningen

Tags: clojure-java-interop

Package Clojure and Java(springboot)  source codes into a JAR file with  leiningen
i run lein uberjar ,
so it happen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fojXR.jpg)

Comment: clojure and java source codes  use diffent namespace

Comment: What is your question actually? Please read this carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Don't write question in comments. Write your questions clearly.